# add postfix in <input> of php

Tags: php, postfix-notation

I wanted to add a currency postfix into the input slider using this code:

```
 if($service_finder_options['search-price']) {
     $html .= '
         <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-6">
             <h5 class="sf-tilte">'.esc_html__('Filter by Price Interval','service-finder').':</h5> 
             <input name="price" type="text" class="sf-price-filter span2" value="" data-slider-min="'.esc_attr($minpricerange).''esc_html__('AED', 'service-finder').'" data-slider-max="'.esc_attr($maxpricerange).''esc_html__('AED', 'service-finder').'" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[0,0]"/>
             <b class="sf-minimum-price">'.service_finder_money_format($minpricerange).'</b>
             <b class="sf-maximum-price">'.service_finder_money_format($maxpricerange).'</b>
         </div>
     ';
 }
```

This code outputs the price range slider. But it is not working, It is suppose to output 'AED' in front of 'minprice' & 'maxprice'. If I remove the `'esc_html__('AED', 'service-finder').'` , then it works.Please help me use the right code to display AED text in front range value. I am beginner at this, so please don't be harsh.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "it is not working": How are you testing it? What is the expected result? What is happening instead?

Comment: Okay, Please check now @IMSoP